# ^M character in mysql query log, where does it come from?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, centos

I am using PDO for php and. Parameters are binding right. However when I check my mysql-query.log on CentOS 5.6

I get the following

```
UPDATE 
  ^ M site_folder_pages ^ M 
SET
  ^ M ^ M title = 'Schanz, Hermann',
  ^ M `desc` = 'Telefonnummer, E-Mailadresse',
  ^ M declared_encoding = NULL,
  ^ M detected_encoding = NULL,
  ^ M word_count = '230',
  ^ M last_checked = NOW(),
  ^ M date_modified = NOW() ^ M 
WHERE ^ M url_hash = '0001843c8b7bb28b46323fd1e8a3efa5' ^ M 
  AND site_id = '52f2b2940f79c1f7d623b066b2bce2e5'
```

Having this, I am not really sure if this query was executed right or the "^M" character was only added on the log file and not the actual query.

Doing a quick search in google I also find queries with the same characters:
[Query with ^M](http://blog.cnizz.com/2011/03/31/mysql-slow-query-log-analyzing-parsing-and-optimizing-slow-queries/)

Is it just on the log? or is it really executed with that character hence there was an error during the execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^M` is the on-screen representation of a carriage return in many UNIX terminals. What you're probably looking at is a log file and/or query string containing Windows-style line endings (`\r\n`), but reading it in UNIX mode (`\n`) and thus the carriage returns (`\r` = `^M`) are showing up.

Since both `\r` and `\n` are whitespace characters, MySQL ignores them, so it won't cause an actual problem.

Comment: I guess somebody opened the logs on WinSCP hmm that explains it.

Answer (score 2):

`^M` corresponds to `chr(13)`, also represented as `\r`, and is the carriage return.

- Unix line Terminator in Unix is only `CHR(10)` (or `\n`, the new line character)
- Windows terminators are `chr(13)` . `chr(10)` (or also as `"\r\n"`, return and new line).

MySQL will ignore all of these characters as whitespace, so you don't have to worry.